# Error constructor

Tags: java, constructor

soy nuevo en Stack y tenia una duda a ver si me podeis echar una mano, estoy creando un programa que crea un tanque en un tablero, y quiero que cada vez que se inice una partida, la posicion en la que se inice sea random.

El problema surge cuando, intento invocar a un constructor mediante otro constructor y no se porque, tambien lo he intentado con un setter/getter

Muchas gracias de antemano!

```js
package tanque;

public class Tanque {
   
    private int columna;
    private int fila;
    private final String DIRECIONES = "NESO";
    private String direccion = "N";
    
   public Tanque(){
       this(generarNumeros(),generarNumeros(),getDireccion());
   }
    
    public Tanque(int fila, int columna, String direccion){
        this.fila = fila;
        this.columna = columna;
        this.direccion = direccion;
    
    }
    
    public static int generarNumeros(){
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion){
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }
    
    public String getDireccion(){
        return direccion;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Tanque t1 = new Tanque();
        System.out.println("la columa es: " + t1.columna);
        System.out.println("la columa es: " + t1.fila);
        System.out.println(t1.direccion);

    }

 
    
   
}
```

Gracias!

Comment: Hola Gorge231, pon tu código para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: Gracias! ya esta colgado!

Comment: Cual es el error que te da?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes llamar desde el constructor por defecto al contructor con los tres parametros, pero se hace mas confuso.

Tu problema esta en

> this(generarNumeros(),generarNumeros(),getDireccion());

No puedes llamar directamente a tu metodo `getDireccion()`

Una **posible solucion** seria crear un nuevo metodo que genere la direcion variando entre los valores `"NESO"`, asi:

```
   public static String generarDireccion(){
        int dir = (int) (Math.random() * 4);
        return   String.valueOf(DIRECIONES.charAt(dir));
    }
```

En la llamada al constructor con tres parametros cambialo con el nuevo metodo:

```
this(generarNumeros(),generarNumeros(),generarDireccion());
```

Y finalmente cambias a static tu variable `DIRECCIONES`:

```
private static final String DIRECIONES = "NESO";
```

Probado y funcionando:

```
la columa es: 40
la columa es: 46
E

la columa es: 17
la columa es: 43
N
```

Comment: Hola y en el caso de generarDirecciones si quiero que lo haga en sentido de las agujas del reloj? Como lo podria implementar?

Comment: Y gracias de antemano!!!!!

Comment: si te refieres a crear 'Tanques' con direccion en sentido de las agujas del reloj, una solucion seria pasarle como parametro al momento de crear una instancia en tu main, asi Tanque t1 = new Tanque("N"); Tanque t2 = new Tanque("E"); etc,

Answer (score 0):

El error que da es que no puedes llamar al constructor con parámetros desde el constructor por defecto. Debe ser al revés y siempre siendo la primera linea de código del constructor. Si lo que quieres es llamar al constructor por defecto y que este te genere números aleatorios debes hacer la siguiente modificación.

```
public class Tanque {

    private int columna;
    private int fila;
    private final String DIRECIONES = "NESO";
    private String direccion = "N";

    public Tanque(){
       this.fila = generarNumeros();
       this.columna = generarNumeros();
       this.direccion = direccion; // O tambien getDireccion();
    }

    /*
    public Tanque(int fila, int columna, String direccion){ //Desde este constructor puedes llamar al de por defecto
        this(); // Aunque ya no tendria sentido ya que le vas a asignar los nuevos parametros en teoria 

    }*/

    public static int generarNumeros(){
        return (int) (Math.random() * 50 + 1);
    }

    public void setDireccion(String direccion){
        this.direccion = direccion;
    }

    public String getDireccion(){
        return direccion;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Tanque t1 = new Tanque();
        System.out.println("la columa es: " + t1.columna);
        System.out.println("la columa es: " + t1.fila);
        System.out.println(t1.direccion);

    }




}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!